# Querying the result of a Procedure, PL/SQL ( Oracle DBMS )

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written a procedure which checks the amount of vacant rooms a property has.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prop_vacancy_query(
p_property_id       properties.tracking_id%TYPE
)
IS
property_refcur     SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_prop_rooms        properties.num_rooms%TYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN property_refcur FOR 
    'SELECT COUNT(room_status) FROM rooms 
     JOIN properties ON
     properties.property_id = rooms.property_id
     WHERE room_status = :status AND properties.tracking_id = :track_id' USING     'VACANT', p_property_id;
LOOP
    FETCH property_refcur INTO v_prop_rooms;
    EXIT WHEN property_refcur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Available Rooms: ' || v_prop_rooms);
END LOOP;
CLOSE property_refcur;
END;
```

I want to use this procedure in a trigger to automatically set the status of the property too 'OCCUPIED' when the amount of rooms available returns as 0.

I have tried

```
IF prop_vacancy_query(:NEW.property_status) = 0 THEN
   :NEW.property_status := 'OCCUPIED';
END IF;
```

But this does not work.  How would I go about calling this procedure with conditional logic in my trigger?  Or is this not possible.

NOTE: I am also worried about the performance issues this may entail, I am not sure how else I could handle auto updating when the DB updates, any pointer to how I could solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a `OUT` variable in your procedure and use it. Or change it as a function. `prop_vacancy_query()` doesn't return anything... so you cannot call this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you have a piece of code whose only purpose is to run queries and return a value, use a `FUNCTION`, not a `PROCEDURE`.  Procedures should be doing some sort of manipulation of the data.

Second, if you do not need dynamic SQL, don't use dynamic SQL.  It's generally a bit slower but, more importantly, it is much, much harder to write, support, and debug.  Plus, you're turning compile-time exceptions into run-time exceptions so you won't find your syntax errors until you try to run your code.

You can simplify your code rather significantly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_vacancies(
    p_property_id       properties.tracking_id%TYPE
  )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_prop_rooms        properties.num_rooms%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(room_status) 
    INTO v_prop_rooms
    FROM rooms 
         JOIN properties ON
         properties.property_id = rooms.property_id
   WHERE room_status = 'VACANT'
     AND properties.tracking_id = p_property_id;

  RETURN v_prop_rooms;
END;
```

Then you can call the function in the way that you originally wanted

```
IF prop_vacancy_query(:NEW.property_status) = 0 THEN
   :NEW.property_status := 'OCCUPIED';
END IF;
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for this solution - I am relatively new to writing PL/SQL blocks, and although I knew what I wanted to do I wasn't sure how to achieve it, hence why I used a procedure over a function.  This makes perfect sense, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prop_vacancy_query(
p_property_id       properties.tracking_id%TYPE
status      OUT   NUMBER
)
.
.
.
status := 0
END;
/
```

And call this way

```
outstatus NUMBER:= -1;

prop_vacancy_query(:NEW.property_id,outstatus);
IF out status = 0 THEN
   :NEW.property_status := 'OCCUPIED';
END IF;
```